# BSOD Dell Vostro 3550 with OS Win 8 x64

Tags: windows-8, 64-bit, bsod, dell-vostro

I often get BSOD on my notebook Dell Vostro 3550 with OS Win 8 x64.

I tried analyze memory.dmp and minidump with Debugging Tools Windows (http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2012/07/18/reading-a-memory-dmp-or-other-dmp-file.aspx) but I couldn’t find root of my problem.

After analyze minidump I found this:

```
EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.

FAULTING_IP: 
ndis!ndisPcwCollectData+143
fffff880`01916e0f 8b4008          mov     eax,dword ptr [rax+8]

CONTEXT:  fffff8801b27c8b0 -- (.cxr 0xfffff8801b27c8b0)
.cxr 0xfffff8801b27c8b0
rax=f680000fff300000 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=fffffa8007ac21a0
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=fffffa800ba3f9d8 rdi=fffffa800ba3f040
rip=fffff88001916e0f rsp=fffff8801b27d2b0 rbp=fffff8801b27d3b0
 r8=0000000000000000  r9=0000000000000000 r10=fffffa800810c250
r11=0000000001f8a2dc r12=fffff8801b27d6b0 r13=0000000000000004
r14=0000000000000004 r15=0000077fe4d82b98
iopl=0         nv up ei ng nz na po nc
cs=0010  ss=0018  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010286
ndis!ndisPcwCollectData+0x143:
fffff880`01916e0f 8b4008          mov     eax,dword ptr [rax+8] ds:002b:f680000f`ff300008=????????
.cxr
Resetting default scope

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x3B

PROCESS_NAME:  vmware-authd.e

CURRENT_IRQL:  1

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff880018531c3 to fffff88001916e0f

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff880`1b27d2b0 fffff880`018531c3 : fffff8a0`003ee2f0 fffff8a0`003f99f0 00000000`00000000 fffff8a0`003f9998 : ndis!ndisPcwCollectData+0x143
fffff880`1b27d570 fffff880`01853522 : fffff880`1b27d6b0 fffff8a0`03455958 fffff8a0`03455910 fffff8a0`00000005 : pcw!PcwpCollectNotification+0xc7
fffff880`1b27d5f0 fffff880`018537e3 : 00000000`00000000 fffff880`1b27d739 00000000`0001b758 00000000`00000000 : pcw!PcwpCollectQueryItem+0x8e
fffff880`1b27d680 fffff880`01854611 : fffff880`1b27d8b8 00000000`00000008 00000000`01f82008 fffff880`1b27d8b8 : pcw!PcwpCollectQuery+0xf7
fffff880`1b27d7a0 fffff880`01854f06 : 00000000`00000004 fffff880`01854eb2 d4005cfd`32810bd1 fffff8a0`03bd77e0 : pcw!PcwpIoctlCollect+0x3d
fffff880`1b27d7d0 fffff803`524a847a : fffff880`01854d8c fffffa80`05f26060 00000000`00224013 fffff803`524d8074 : pcw!PcwpFastIoDeviceControl+0x17a
fffff880`1b27d890 fffff803`524bda76 : fffffa80`0b799080 fffffa80`00000004 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 : nt!IopXxxControlFile+0x3d9
fffff880`1b27da20 fffff803`520d2453 : ffffffff`fffffffe fffff803`52029e3b 00000000`0000000f 00000000`00000000 : nt!NtDeviceIoControlFile+0x56
fffff880`1b27da90 00000000`771d2ad2 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x13
00000000`022dec08 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x771d2ad2
```

Also I tried update all driver with SW such as driver genius or driver reviwer.

Usually I get BSOD when I use some download manager such as freerapid, jdownloader orfree download manager. IMHO problem can be in network drivers.

Here are dmp files:

Sory I can’t post more than one link so I must edited urls.

**minidump**

hxxp://ul.to/zurf6h05

**memory.dmp**

hxxp://ul.to/6gnqentv

Can anybody help me and find where is problem?

Finnaly I updated drivers for Win8 from ftp://ftp.dell.com/Pages/Drivers/vostro-3550.html and I will see if this update helps.

Thank you very much

Comment: This looks like to be a driver error cauzsed by VMWare.  Have you ran memtestx86 to verify its not your memory causing this problem?

Comment: update NOD32. I see driver ehdrv.sys is involved. Your driver is from 2012. Get the version 7 from the website.

Comment: @magicandre1981: I updated eset and I will see if this problem is fixed.

Comment: @magicandre1981: Could you post your comment about nod32 as answer? I will accept it. Thank you

Comment: @imodin ok, I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update NOD32 to Version 7, you still use an older version from 2012:

```
0xfffff8801b27c578 : 0xfffff8801b27c730 : 0xfffff803523ca800 : nt!CmpRegistryLock
0xfffff8801b27c618 : 0xfffff803524d8074 : nt!NtQueryValueKey+0x612
0xfffff8801b27c668 : 0xfffff8035213d710 :  !du "DeviceDesc"
0xfffff8801b27c680 : 0xfffff8801b27c810 : 0xfffff88001916e0f : ndis!ndisPcwCollectData+0x143
Unable to load image \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\ehdrv.sys, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for ehdrv.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for ehdrv.sys
0xfffff8801b27c6a0 : 0xfffff8801b27c7e0 : 0xfffff803523a93e8 : "nt!KiInitialPCR <PERF> (nt+0x3303e8)"
0xfffff8801b27c6b8 : 0xfffff80352554a44 : nt!CmpCallCallBacks+0x3e4


    Loaded symbol image file: ehdrv.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\ehdrv.sys
    Image name: ehdrv.sys
    Timestamp:        Fri Dec 21 13:03:30 2012
```